# How to use data to set other data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to set data in one components that is defined by other data in that component.
something like...

```js
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    FirstName: "Mark", 
    LastName: "Zuckerberg",
    FullName: this.FirstName + this.LastName
  }),
  // ..
})
```

Error

Comment: You’re looking for [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

Comment: Also, it’s more common to name variables and properties using camelCase (i.e. `firstName`, `fullName`, etc) rather that StudlyCase.

Answer (score 2):

Use `computed`.

Insert below code under `data`.

```
computed: {
    FullName() {
         return this.FirstName + this.LastName;
    },
}
```

You can use `this.FullName` inside the component.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

To get derived data, Vue has feature called `computed` properties

```
data: () => ({
  FirstName: Mark, 
  LastName: Zuckerberg,
}),
computed: () => {
  FullName() {
    return this.FirstName + this.LastName
  }
}
```

Moreover computed properties are cached, so it will only be recomputed when the associated data are changes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

Something like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#addr",
  template: `<div class = templateField>
      <h1>Hello {{ firstName }}!</h1>
      <p>Hello {{ lastName }}!</p>
      <p>{{fullName}}</p>
  </div>`,
  data: {
    firstName: "Mark",
    lastName: "Zuckerberg"
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: function () {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  }
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/a9d9c57b7d109bd9525f641eb2d81724?editors=0010) is a working example.